# python, matplotlib, svg and hyperlinks in text labels

Tags: python, hyperlink, svg, matplotlib

In [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), it is possible to [create SVG figures with hyperlinks](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/hyperlinks.html).

For example, I can use the `scatter` method to draw markers so that each individual marker is a hyperlink.

However, some of my markers have text labels that I have created with the `text` method. Can I somehow turn the text labels into hyperlinks as well?

---

So far I have been able to achieve the following. First, create a text label with a bounding box so that the `bbox` dictionary has a `url` parameter:

```
ax.text(x, y, label, bbox=dict(boxstyle=..., url=url))
```

Then patch `matplotlib/backends/backend_svg.py` (version 1.1.1) slightly, replacing

```
self.writer.end('</a>')
```

with

```
self.writer.end('a')
```

Now it *almost* works. I can click on the area that *surrounds* the text, but not the text itself (put otherwise, if I have black text on white background, I can click anywhere in the white parts, but not in the black parts).

---

What is the easiest way to turn the entire text label into a hyperlink (both the text and its bounding box)?

Ideally, I would prefer a solution that does not require that I patch the matplotlib library.

Comment: Looks like you have found a bug. Do you mind reporting it on the github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib issue tracker? If your eager, this would make a fairly do-able first contribution too. ;-)  HTH

Comment: @pelson: Well, the `</a>` part is of course a bug, and certainly it would be great if someone fixed it. However, the main issue is that some features are missing, and I do not know if these features will be ever implemented in Matplotlib. I cannot really wait for that, and therefore I was looking for some tricks that I could use in my own code. I am already doing things like post-processing the SVG code that was produced by Matplotlib, so I do not mind if the tricks are ugly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution seems to work fine.

- Set the `gid` attribute of the text element to a unique string:

  ```
  ax.text(x, y, label, gid='foo')
  ```
- Create the SVG file as usual; there are no hyperlinks yet.
- Use, e.g., `lxml` to parse the SVG file. Find the unique `<g>` element with the attribute `id="foo"`. Modify the XML tree: replace `<g>...</g>` with `<a ...><g>...</g></a>`. Save the result.

The same approach seems to work in general; many elements accept a `gid` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

[This change](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/2d729773c8c9f4155831fe6cf510333fd536e260) in matplotlib git enables rendering Text object's URL fields as links in the rendered SVG.

Including the code by @travc this could look like:

```
url = "https://matplotlib.org/"
txt = plt.text(x, y, url, url=url, bbox = dict(color='w', alpha=0.01, url=url)
```

Comment: This is very cool IMO.  As of 1.3.1, just using `set_url()` for an artist seems to work for everything except the actual text.  mtd's little patch fixes that (it has been merged, so one could just update matplotlib).

Comment: One probably wants to also make the background of the text a link.  For 1.3.1 that can easily be done with something like: `txt = text(x,y,'something', url='something')`
`txt.set_bbox(dict(color='w', alpha=0.01, url=txt.get_url())`
The color and alpha is a bit hackish... at least version 1.3.1 doesn't seem to create the box if color is none or alpha is 0.